# Doing multiple sort parameters on namedTuple in python

Tags: python, sorting, namedtuple

I would like to sort a list of namedTuple base on 2 parameters.  For example, my data has a list of tuples containing (ExampleTuples):

```
Example(key=0,time=15)
Example(key=1,time=50)
Example(key=2,time=15)
Example(key=4,time=3)
```

I want to sort them with descending order base on time, but also sort them with ascending order of key.  Basically I want the sort to be:

```
Example(key=1,time=50)
Example(key=0,time=15)
Example(key=2,time=15)
Example(key=4,time=3)
```

If I use:

```
SortedTuple = list(reversed(sorted(ExampleTuples, key=lambda x: (x.time,x.key))))
```

I get:

```
Example(key=1,time=50)
Example(key=2,time=15)
Example(key=0,time=15)
Example(key=4,time=3)
```

Whats the best way to get what I want?

Comment: just negate one of your values; `key=lambda x: (x.time,-x.key))` something like that.

Comment: Oh that easy? lol thanks.  It worked

Comment: see that's a common problem (I linked to the original question)